# NX CLI: Missing Platform Dependency

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, command-line-interface, nrwl-nx

NX CLI Docker-Compose Issue: Missing Platform Dependency
Like the title states I am receiving the following error message...

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMArG.png)

In short...I am trying to have some tests on a server(wolverine) that I have written using NestJS, when trying to run `docker-compose up wolverine` the image and container seem to finish building but then I get  **NX Missing Platform Dependency**
**The Nx CLI could not find or load the native binary for your supported platform (linux-x64)**

I am using nx v17.2.8 if this is at all relevant...

I am really at a lost here to what might cause this issue...
Thanks in advance.

I have exhausted all the suggestions in the troubleshooting [LINK](https://nx.dev/recipes/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-nx-install-issues) that is attached to the error message.

- Tried deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running `npm install`
- Made sure I installed the most recent version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
- "Confirm that you see @nx/nx-plaform-arch in your node_modules folder (e.g. @nx/nx-darwin-arm64, @nx/nx-win32-x64-msvc, etc).":

[On my windows 10 64 bit PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsezH.png)

On my docker desktop my docker builder is desktop-linux and I have both of the linux-platform-architectures installed on nx

[On the docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgwgP.png)

here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:18.16.1-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY package*.json /home/node/

RUN npm install

COPY . /home/node/

RUN npm run build wolverine

FROM node:18.16.1-alpine as wolverine

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY --from=builder /home/node/dist/apps/wolverine/package*.json /home/app/

COPY --from=builder /home/node/dist/ /home/app/dist/

RUN npm ci --ignore-scripts

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

CMD ["sh", "-c", "node dist/apps/wolverine/main.js"]
```

Expecting it to not get this error and start listening to the configured port.